# Expected ',' seperator When adding images

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Button: UIButton!


Imagenames = ["#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image2")", "#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image1"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func Buttonpress(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let imageV = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))

    ImageView.image = UIImage(named: Imagenames[ImageView])
}
```

How can I fix this issue? please help. Running the latest version of Xcode

Answer (score 2):

You forget a simple `)` in your code, and you have an extra `"`:

```
Imagenames = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image2"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image1")]
```

That should save your life :) haha, sometimes happens

Comment: Firstly he *would* be missing a `)` as well. Secondly missing characters is a close reason, not a reason for an answer.

Comment: And your code will still not compile, 3 reasons are more than enough for a downvote.

Comment: @luk2302 Thank you so much

Comment: OP didn't forget a `"`, there's actually extra `"`s.

Comment: let Imagenames = ["#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image2")","#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image1")"] this is what i put in and still have the same problem.

Comment: @Nubbie as the more experiences users told you, you don't have to put string inside, just do: var Imagenames = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image2"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image1")]

Comment: @Nubbie Don't forget to accept only one answer with the (✓) top left of the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

`#imageLiteral`s are not supposed to go into a `String`. Your code should be

```
Imagenames = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image2"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image1")]
```

*As you can already see the code is properly highlighted both in Xcode as well as on Stackoverflow.*

Note that you are missing a `var` or `let` in front of `Imagenames` as well. And that your variable should start with a lower case, e.g. `images`. Your functions should follow that naming as well by the way.

Then you should change your code logic inside `Buttonpress` to be:

```
ImageView.image = images[imageV]
```

Putting all the naming advices together your code should probably be something like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

let images = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image2"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image1")]

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let imageIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))

    imageView.image = images[imageIndex]
}
```

Comment: @Nubbie if my or the other answer solved your problem please click on the checkmark on the top left of the answer.

Comment: thanks @DamianLattenero, I copied to much in an effort to round things up :/

Comment: @luk2302 haha no problem... this comunity is about grow up together, and have more than two eyes ;), thanks to you for the patiente